# How to save the ckeditor value in Ajax Angular?

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, codeigniter

I have a problem in saving the CKEDITOR value in my database using the Angular AJAX. I don't know if it is an Angular issue or just PHP. By the way I am using CodeIgniter 3 in my application.

Here's a bit of my code I hope you understand what I have:

My CKEDITOR:
Here I am saving an agreement

Here's the AJAX save:

```
$scope.saveContent = function() {

    $scope.totals = [{
        'subtotals' : computeGrandTotal(),
        'vat_rate'  : quoteList.vat_rate,
        'grandtotal': computePercentage()
    }];

    $http({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/tutorial/submitQuotation'); ?>",
        method: 'POST',
        data: $.param({ 
                quotation: $scope.quoteHeader.items, 
                msc: quoteList, //here goes the agreeement content
                totals: $scope.totals 
            }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data){
        alert('Data successfully inserted!');
    }).error(function(){
        alert('Error Occured!');
    });

}
```

And in my model I am doing this:

```
$sqlInsertQuotationAgreement = "INSERT INTO quotation_agreement SET quoatation_id = " . (int)$quotationID . ", agreement = '" . $agreement . "'";
$queryInsertQuotationAgreement = $this->db->query($sqlInsertQuotationAgreement);
```

And when I check my developer console I got an error because the value from my CKEDITOR is rendered in HTML and not in code.

I tried to use stripslashes() and $this->db->escape() but still error.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Ok I tried to use this function and it gets my html data: `htmlspecialchars()` But I got this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's material and rubble as well as machiner and equipment and shall be generally c' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my error. Here's what i did in the query:

```
$sqlInsertQuotationAgreement = "INSERT INTO quotation_agreement SET quotation_id = " . (int)$quotationID . ", agreement = \"" . htmlspecialchars($agreement) . "\"";
```